# How to get all possible partitions for a list in Scala

Tags: scala, list, combinations

I have a list of string, e.g. `List("A", "B", "C")`. I would like to get all the possible partitions of it in Scala. The result I expect is:

```
def func(List[String]): List[List[String]] = {
// some operations
}
In: func(List("A", "B", "C"))
Out: 
[
[["A"], ["B"], ["C"]], 
[["A", "B"], ["C"]], 
[["A", "C"], ["B"]], 
[["B", "C"], ["A"]], 
[["A", "B", "C"]], 
]
```

Comment: How do you want to handle repeated values, i.e. `List("A","B","A")`?

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on when you say partitions for a list?

Comment: You function signature appears to be wrong. Shouldn't the result be `List[List[List[String]]]`?

Comment: You are looking for the power set

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution using `Set`:

```
def partitions[T](seq: TraversableOnce[T]): Set[Set[Set[T]]] = {
  def loop(set: Set[T]): Set[Set[Set[T]]] =
    if (set.size < 2) {
      Set(Set(set))
    } else {
      set.subsets.filter(_.nonEmpty).flatMap(sub =>
        loop(set -- sub).map(_ + sub - Set.empty)
      ).toSet
    }

  loop(seq.toSet)
}
```

Using `Set` makes the logic easier, but it does remove duplicate values if they are present in the original list. The same logic can be use for `List` but you need to implement the set-like operations such as `subsets`.

---

Just for reference, here is an implementation using `List` which will preserve duplicates in the input list.

```
def partitions[T](list: List[T]): List[List[List[T]]] =
  list match {
    case Nil | _ :: Nil => // 0/1 elements
      List(List(list))
    case head :: tail => // 2+ elements
      partitions(tail).flatMap(part => {
        val joins =
          part.indices.map(i =>
            part.zipWithIndex.map { case (p, j) =>
              if (i == j) {
                head +: p
              } else {
                p
              }
            }
          )

        (List(head) +: part) +: joins
      })
  }
```